# Error in using WITH clause and INTERSECT in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, select, with-statement, intersect

I have two SQL queries;
First one is:

```
with b as (select person_id from people where name='Ward Bond' and born=1903)
select title_id from b natural join crew;
```

Which is producing correct results and is OK.
Another one is:

```
with c as (select person_id from people where name='John Wayne' and born=1907)
select title_id from c natural join crew;
```

Which is also totally OK and producing correct results. As soon as I try to find the intersection of these two queries using the following query:

```
with b as (select person_id from people where name='Ward Bond' and born=1903) select title_id from b natural join crew 
intersect
with c as (select person_id from people where name='John Wayne' and born=1907) select title_id from c natural join crew;
```

I get the error `Error: near "with": syntax error`
I'm using SQLite3. Can you please help me to find the problem? The thing I'm trying to get is straightforward; I want to have the intersection of these two temporary tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for SQLite:

```
select * from (
  with b as (
    select person_id 
    from people 
    where name='Ward Bond' and born=1903
  ) 
  select title_id from b natural join crew
)
intersect
select * from (
  with c as (
    select person_id 
    from people 
    where name='John Wayne' and born=1907
  ) 
  select title_id from c natural join crew
);
```

Another way to get the intersected rows:

```
with cte(name, born) as (values ('Ward Bond', 1903), ('John Wayne', 1907))
select c.title_id 
from crew c natural join people p
where (p.name, p.born) in cte
group by c.title_id
having count(distinct p.person_id) = 2;
```

Comment: thanks for your guidance. using "view" also works

Answer (score 1):

That's how I did it using `view`:

```
create view a as select person_id from people where name='Ward Bond' and born=1903;
create view b as select person_id from people where name='John Wayne' and born=1907;
with c as 
(select title_id from a natural join crew
intersect
select title_id from b natural join crew) 
select primary_title from c natural join titles;
```

Comment: You can improve the readability of your answer by formatting the SQL so that the statements are displayed across multiple lines, i.e., 
CREATE VIEW a
AS 
SELECT person_id
FROM people
WHERE name = 'Ward Bond'
AND born = 1903;